# Anbox and OpenLDAP to Active Directory for SSO

Tags: active-directory, openldap, anbox

Anbox and OpenLDAP to Active Directory for SSO

We would love to use Anbox with our Active Directory for user authentication.

We have Windows 10 OS Instance using Active Direction for logon, being able to provide an Anbox/Android device to the users would be our goal

Finding the documentation has been a challenge, a how to document would be helpful

Comment: Anbox is an Ubuntu program for those reviewers who might consider retracting their close votes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean SSO support in the Anbox Cloud dashboard? We currently only support Ubuntu SSO for login.

There is a `disable_auth` configuration option on the `anbox-cloud-dashboard` charm (see https://charmhub.io/anbox-cloud-dashboard/configure#disable_auth) which could be use to disable Ubuntu SSO and then you can add your authentication layer through a reverse proxy. I would though not recommend this as some features may depend on the dashboard having its own authentication mechanism in place.

Furthermore the dashboard provides a lot of access to the Anbox Cloud deployment which regular users should not necessarily have.

The best option is if you implement your own client [by using the streaming SDK](https://anbox-cloud.io/docs/tut/stream-client) and then you can authenticate your users in whichever way you like.